# Use Variables for ChildSnapshot - Keys in Firebase (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to use a variable for the ChildSnapshot but it does not work. This is how it works.

```
firebase.database(CustomerDatabase).ref('Customer').once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (ChildSnapshot) {
        console.log(ChildSnapshot.val().Firstname);
    }
```

This is how I would like it to work. But that throws an error.

```
let child_var = "Firstname";
firebase.database(CustomerDatabase).ref('Customer').once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (ChildSnapshot) {
        console.log(ChildSnapshot.val().child_var);
    }
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `[]` notation for that:

```
console.log(ChildSnapshot.val()[child_var]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common JavaScript problem. What you are actually doing in the second code block is attempting to access the property named "child_var" instead of the one named "Firstname". Use bracketed property access to use a variable to access properties:

```js
ChildSnapshot.val()[child_var]
```

Further reading: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)